# Is there a way to instantiate key with JQ?

Tags: filter, jq

Is there a way for jq to instantiate a key to output?

Given:

```
{
  "foo": "bizz",
  "bar": "buzz",
  "bat": [
    "somestring"
  ]
}
```

I would like to do something like `jq '. | {foobar.foo, foobar.bar}'`
and have it output:

```
{
  "foobar": {
    "foo": "bizz",
    "bar": "buzz"
  }
}
```

without having to make the initial `foobar` dictionary.

Comment: Try `jq '{foobar: {foo, bar}}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to consider:

```
{foobar: del(.bat)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to "create a dictionary" first. Simply define your object's structure (`.|` is a redundant no-op, it can be left out):

```
jq '{ foobar: { foo, bar } }'
```